# Django on Dreamhost: Display or log console output?

Tags: python, django, apache, passenger, dreamhost

I have a Django install on Dreamhost, and I'm trying to figure out if there is anyway I can see the console output from my Django scripts. When I run it on the devserver (./manage.py runserver), the output from any print statements goes right to the console it was run from. Is there a logfile or any way to see this information when it's running on Dreamhost via Passenger?

Thanks

Comment: This is a system administration question, it should be asked on ServerFault. Voting to move.

Comment: I disagree, this is a programming question regarding how to debug code on a live Dreamhost setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ADMIN mail configured you can receive the error logs by mail:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/

Also take a look to django-sentry, it's a very good exception logging app:

https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry